PowerBI: ADO.NET: Python script error : ValueError: No objects to concatenate
I am trying to run python script in power BI but getting following error. Script is running fine in Spyder environment and giving results as well as working fine at Power BI script writting and it is showing up the output tables however after clicking on each table it is not getting loaded into Power BI as data. I have ran similar code using other Broker's API it was working fine however for IB it is giving error.
enter image description here
Following code:

import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
today_date = dt.date.today() + timedelta(1)
#today_date = today_date.strftime("20%y-%m-%d")
import yfinance as yf

import sys 

sys.path.append(r'F:\Projects\!!!Python Data\Quants Strategies\!Interactive Broker')

import IB_API

print("Testing IB's API as an imported library:")


US_Stock_Portfolio = IB_API.read_positions()
US_Stock_Portfolio = US_Stock_Portfolio.reset_index()

US_Stock_Portfolio = US_Stock_Portfolio[['Symbol', 'Quantity']]


US_Stock_Ticker = []

for ticker in US_Stock_Portfolio['Symbol']:
    US_Stock_Ticker.append(ticker)
    


# Performance 5 Years

Start_date_Perf = today_date - timedelta(365*5)
End_date_Perf = today_date

#VaR_Date 1 year

Start_date_Var = today_date - timedelta(365)
End_date_Var = today_date


#SVaR date 2019-2020

Start_date_SVar = '2020-1-1'
End_date_SVar = '2020-12-31'

Name = ['Performance', 'VaR', 'SVaR']
S_date_list = [Start_date_Perf, Start_date_Var, Start_date_SVar  ]
E_date_list = [End_date_Perf, End_date_Var, End_date_SVar ]



for i in range(0,3):
    US_Stock_Data = yf.download(US_Stock_Ticker, S_date_list[i] , E_date_list[i], period='1d', progress=False)['Adj Close']
    US_Stock_Data = pd.DataFrame(US_Stock_Data)
    US_Stock_Data.index = US_Stock_Data.index.tz_localize(None)
    US_Stock_Data = US_Stock_Data.reset_index()
    US_Stock_Data.sort_values(by='Date', ascending = True, inplace = True)
    US_Stock_Data = US_Stock_Data.replace("", None).bfill()
    US_Stock_Data = US_Stock_Data.replace("", None).ffill()
    US_Stock_Data[['Date','Time']] = US_Stock_Data['Date'].apply(str).str.split(' ', expand = True)
    US_Stock_Data = US_Stock_Data.drop('Time', axis=1)
    US_Stock_Data = US_Stock_Data.drop_duplicates(subset=['Date'])
    #bm_data.to_excel(r"F:\Projects\Company analysis\Stock Data\BM_data.xlsx",index=False)
    """
    if Name[i] == 'Performance':
        US_Stock_Data_Perf = US_Stock_Data.copy()
    
    elif Name[i] == 'VaR':
        US_Stock_Data_VaR = US_Stock_Data.copy()
    
    elif Name[i] == 'SVaR':
        US_Stock_Data_SVaR = US_Stock_Data.copy()  
    """
    ### Calculating new dfs for Portfolio Market Value
    US_Stock_Data_new = US_Stock_Data.copy()
    
    #IN_Stock_Data_new.rename(columns = {'Ticker':'Yahoo Ticker'}, inplace = True)
    
    for j in US_Stock_Portfolio['Symbol']:
        
        US_Stock_Data_new[j] = US_Stock_Data_new[j] * float(US_Stock_Portfolio.loc[US_Stock_Portfolio['Symbol'] == j]['Quantity'].iloc[0])
        
        #US_Stock_Data_new[j] = US_Stock_Data_new[j] * float(US_Stock_Portfolio.loc[US_Stock_Portfolio['Symbol'] == j]['Quantity'])
        
    Date = []

    for k in US_Stock_Data_new['Date']:
        Date.append(k)

    US_Stock_Data_new = US_Stock_Data_new.drop(['Date'], axis=1)

    Port_Value = []

    for l in range(0, len(US_Stock_Data_new)):
        Port_Value.append(US_Stock_Data_new.loc[l].sum())

    US_Stock_Data_new_perf = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(Date, Port_Value)), columns = ['Date', 'Market Value'])
    
    US_Stock_Data_new_perf['Market Value %'] = US_Stock_Data_new_perf['Market Value'].pct_change()
    US_Stock_Data_new_perf['Market Value % Cumsum'] = US_Stock_Data_new_perf['Market Value %'].cumsum()
    

    print('downloaded data for '+ Name[0])
    
    if Name[i] == 'Performance':
        US_Port_Perf = US_Stock_Data_new_perf.copy()
    
    elif Name[i] == 'VaR':
        US_Port_VaR = US_Stock_Data_new_perf.copy()
    
    elif Name[i] == 'SVaR':
        US_Port_SVaR = US_Stock_Data_new_perf.copy()   



VaR_01 = []
SVaR_01= []

VaR_05 = []
SVaR_05 = []


Temp = [] 
Var_df = pd.DataFrame(Temp)
Var_df['ascending'] = US_Port_VaR['Market Value %'].sort_values(ascending=True)
    
VaR_01.append(Var_df.quantile(0.01).iloc[0])
VaR_05.append(Var_df.quantile(0.05).iloc[0])


Temp = [] 
Var_df = pd.DataFrame(Temp)
Var_df['ascending'] = US_Port_SVaR['Market Value %'].sort_values(ascending=True)
    
SVaR_01.append(Var_df.quantile(0.01).iloc[0])
SVaR_05.append(Var_df.quantile(0.05).iloc[0])
    
   
US_Port_Var_Data = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(VaR_01, VaR_05, SVaR_01,SVaR_05)), columns = ['1D VaR @99%', '1D VaR @95%','1D SVaR @99%', '1D SVaR @95%'])  

US_Port_Var_Data = US_Port_Var_Data.T

US_Port_Var_Data.rename(columns = {0:'US Portfolio'}, inplace = True)

US_Port_Var_Data = US_Port_Var_Data.reset_index()

#US_Stock_Portfolio.to_excel(r'F:\Projects\Company Analysis\Holdings\US_Stock_Portfolio.xlsx')


del US_Stock_Data
del US_Stock_Data_new
del US_Stock_Data_new_perf
del US_Stock_Portfolio
del Var_df

1 query is blocked by the following errors:
US_Port_VaR
ADO.NET: Python script error. ValueError: No objects to concatenate During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: ValueError: No objects to concatenate
US_Port_Var_Data
ADO.NET: Python script error. ValueError: No objects to concatenate During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: ValueError: No objects to concatenate
US_Port_SVaR
ADO.NET: Python script error. ValueError: No objects to concatenate During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: ValueError: No objects to concatenate


Issue is Resolved: It is Power BI limitation that it could not fatch data from API for Multiple dataframe at once or query runs fast so that data is not fatch for all at once. (Somthing like that). Solution was simple I just turn off Parallel loading(PowerBI>Options & setting>Options>Data load> Parallel loading of Tables>One)
